# Unable to install pyinstall in windows 10

Tags: python-3.x

It always shows error and cannot install the module pyInstaller.
I follow the guidelines from [here](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html) but it showed same error as [image: it]

Comment: You need to install PyInstaller module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install pyinstaller:

```
pip install pyinstaller
```